# Where can I migrate a ccTLD to?

Tags: dns, domain-name, godaddy, tld

Lets say I have a domain name *vvv.id*. Where can I transfer the domain to (for example transfer it to *godaddy.com*)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a registrar that handles that *ccTLD*, which is easy to check as they usually have a listing on their main webpage.

You can find a [partial list](http://www.tld-list.com) of registrars here. *Those are not the only ones that exist*.

You'll have choose the one with an affordable price to you for domain transfers.